# MacOS doesn't resolve localhost to 127.0.0.1 (ignores hosts / apache vhosts)

Tags: macos, apache, localhost, hosts, resolve

I ran into the problem, that localhost redirects to a specific domain instead of 127.0.0.1.

My configuration is a local apache/mysql/php installation on MacOS Mojave using vhosts for different projects that are configured in hosts to redirect properly.

When I enter 127.0.0.1 in any browser, I get to my overview page lying in the www root. The same should happen, when I enter localhost in the browser, but instead it redirects to a domain of a project I was working on in the past. It happens also without network connection, so the configuration is on this machine.

My /etc/hosts file:

> ```
> ##
> # Host Database
> #
> # localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
> # when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
> ##
> 127.0.0.1     localhost project1.local project2.local
> 255.255.255.255   broadcasthost
> ::1             localhost
> fe80::1%lo0       localhost
> ```

The first line seems to be ignored and localhost doesn't resolve to 127.0.0.1.

I only have two vhost configurations plus default configuration with no wrong redirection and also the httpd.conf lookes fine. I searched the whole machine with `grep -lr "redirectiondomain.com" *` without results. I tried with apache switched off with the same result and looked up the MacOS network settings but I can't find anything related to the wrong redirection neither any other solution on stackoverflow or google that solves my issue. Has anybody a clue how the wrong redirection of localhost could be set somewhere else?

***Edit:*** My hostname in MacOS is set. I tried localhost without port, with :80 and :8080

Comment: You appear to have changed the line starting `127.0.0.1` which it explicitly says not to do in the preceding line. I would try changing it back and removing your two synonyms then rebooting.

Comment: `localhost` maps to 127.0.0.1 (an IPv4 address) **and** ::1 and fe80::1%lo0 (IPv6 addresses). macOS generally prefers IPv6, and will try those addresses before trying an IPv4 address. What happens if you try to load "http://[::1]/" and "http://[fe80:1::1]/" (for obscure reasons, the last one is the equivalent of fe80::1%lo0)?

Comment: @GordonDavisson both lead correctly to 127.0.0.1

Answer (score 0):

## MacOS Fix the MySQL Socket localhost vs 127.0.0.1 error

The socket is a file that allows MySQL client/server communication. Linking where MySQL places the socket and where macOS thinks it should be resolves this problem. MySQL puts the socket in `/tmp` and macOS looks for it in `/var/mysql`. Run the following commands in Terminal and this should resolve the problem

```
sudo mkdir /var/mysql

sudo ln -s /tmp/mysql.sock /var/mysql/mysql.sock
```